# Creating URL from area to application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an area called "Admin".

I can upload images through admin. and would love to display them on the public pages. ie: not an area.

So i have a ImageController.

when i do following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("View","Image", new {id = 1})" />
```

it creates a URL in my Admin area as follows:

```
/Admin/Image/View/1
```

But my controller is within the /Controller folder not in the area.

so I want

```
/Image/View/1
```

How do I get this working both for Admin and for other areas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your image HTML tag to:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("View", "Image", new { id = 1, area = "" })" />
```

This will remove the area part, so it will always refer to a route in the MVC root.

You could maybe insert this line into a Partial or DisplayFor template and pass in the image id.